# Google icons change on :focus

Tags: icons, focus, anchor, materialize

I just started using Google Material icons.

```
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons"
      rel="stylesheet">

<a title="E-mail " href="mailto:es@example.com?subject=RE:&nbsp;Estimate Request"><i class="material-icons md-36 bg_white">email</i></a>
    <a title="Call" href="tel:+15555555"><i class="material-icons md-36 bg_white">call</i></a>
    <a title="Send SMS" href="sms:+5555555"><i class="material-icons md-36 bg_white">message</i></a>
```

Is there a way to highlight the icons on focus so that there is a more obvious visual queue (other than the thin blue border) that the icon is highlighted when tabbed? Like a color change, or an overlay, or displaying the title, or something ...

Here's my css: I've tried adding to the :focus but nothing changes.

```
.material-icons.md-18font-size:18px}
.material-icons.md-24{font-size: 24px} /* Default */
.material-icons.md-36{font-size: 36px}
.material-icons.md-48{font-size: 48px}
.material-icons{color:green /*#663300*/}
.material-icons:active, .material-icons:focus, .material-icons:hover{color:#8bc34a}
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Is it a typo or do you have it the same way in the source code as well? Because, if latter  is the case, then there seems to be a missing `{` in your CSS on the first line, where you have `.material-icons.md-18font-size:18px}`, when it should be `.material-icons.md-18{font-size:18px}`. Fixing it does give a color change on icons, at least on `:hover`.